# Почему клиент не хочет получать данные?

Tags: c#, сеть, сокет, клиент-сервер, udp

```
        public void Listen()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[55555];
            client.Receive(data);
            PlaySound(data);
        }
    }
```

Метод Listen запускается в отдельном потоке, должен получать данные с сервера и проигрывать их(это звук). Но вылазит исключение:
Необработанное исключение типа "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" в System.dll
Дополнительные сведения: Получен недопустимый аргумент
(в методе Receive)

Второй день не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: Какой тип данных имеет переменная client?

Comment: Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваша переменная client типа UdpClient, то боюсь вы неправильно пользуетесь методом Receive. Он принимает адрес отправителя или ANY (от любого адреса) и возвращает массив байт данных.
Примерно так должен выглядеть ваш код:

```
IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
byte[] data = client.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

По-хорошему добавить код получения данных в try и отлавливать нужные вам ошибки

Comment: Я уж и забыл про этот класс. С ним всё работает, спасибо